# Lodash transform array mix of objects and strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I have an array that contains a mix of objects and strings. I need to transform the array into another object array.

The input array:

```
[
  {"text": "Address"},
  {"text": "NewTag"},
  {"text": "Tag"},
  "Address",
  "Name",
  "Profile",
  {"text": "Name"},
]
```

The out array should like this:

```
[
  {"Tag": "Address", Count: 2},
  {"Tag": "Name", Count: 2},
  {"Tag": "NewTag", Count: 1},
  {"Tag": "Profile", Count: 1},
  {"Tag": "Tag", Count: 1},
]
```

Here is my code (it looks stupid):

```
var tags = [], tansformedTags=[];   
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (_.isObject(input[i])) {
    tags.push(input[i]['text']);
  } else {
    tags.push(input[i]);
  }
}
tags = _.countBy(tags, _.identity);
for (var property in tags) {
  if (!tags.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    continue;
  }
  tansformedTags.push({ "Tag": property, "Count": tags[property] });
}
return _.sortByOrder(tansformedTags, 'Tag');
```

I want to know if there is a better and more elegant way to perform this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) and [countBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy):

```
_(arr)
    .map(function(item) {
        return _.get(item, 'text', item);
    })
    .countBy()
    .map(function(value, key) {
        return { Text: key, Count: value };
    })
    .value();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.create(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create a hash table where you can count the properties in your array, then get its properties with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to build your objects.

```js
var count = Object.create(null);
myArray.forEach(function(item) {
  var prop = Object(item) === item ? item.text : item;
  count[prop] = (count[prop] || 0) + 1;
});
Object.keys(count).sort().map(function(key) {
  return {Tag: key, Count: count[key]};
});
```

Comment: The OP is using lodash.  Maybe he/she needs to write code that is compatible with (really) old browsers.

Comment: I like this solution too. Code is concise and clear.